# CouchDB find videos that user not watched

Tags: couchdb

I'm new to Apache CouchDB database.

I have a list of all video (about 10M video, each video has a propery named Category
) and a list of user watched video. How do I write View and query to get list of un-watched video belong to specified user id and category ?

Because it's not like SQL, so I have no idea to try to write my own.

Comment: Here's a good place to start [1.5.4.2. Querying Views and Indexes](https://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/api/ddoc/views.html?highlight=limit#querying-views-and-indexes)

Comment: If you need help, please give specific examples of the documents and the view/ query that you are using.